# How to change a single column of an existing csv with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv file which I can read using `pd.read_csv()`.
In this file i have `SomeBoolean` column that I need to update with new logic.
However when I write the file again using `pd.to_csv()` some other column values are changed, e.g. the `sometimesNaN` column has some empty values which are interpreted as `NaN` while reading the csv, but then they are also written as `NaN` instead of an empty value.

Is there a way in which I can update the `SomeBoolean` column without accidentally affecting the others such as the `sometimesNaN` column?

```
Index   Date         SomeBoolean    Values        sometimesNaN
0       2021-05-18   False          216.351155    NaN
1       2021-05-18   False          876.222176    NaN
2       2021-05-18   False          767.214479    NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider to make Pandas not to interpret empty values in `sometimesNaN` column as `NaN` so that it won't overwritten original empty values when written back.

To achieve this, you can specify the parameter `keep_default_na=False` in reading in the csv during [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) call.

> **keep_default_na : bool, default True**
>
> **Whether or not to include the
> default NaN values when parsing the data. Depending on whether
> na_values is passed in, the behavior is as follows:**
>
> If keep_default_na is True, and na_values are specified, na_values is
> appended to the default NaN values used for parsing.
>
> If keep_default_na is True, and na_values are not specified, only the
> default NaN values are used for parsing.
>
> If keep_default_na is False, and na_values are specified, only the NaN
> values specified na_values are used for parsing.
>
> **If keep_default_na is False, and na_values are not specified, no
> strings will be parsed as NaN.**

Note that this behavior applies to all columns.  So if you have `NaN` values in other columns you want Pandas to interpret the empty values as `NaN` when reading in the csv, you may not be able to use this.